# Search user by custom claim filter

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-identity-server, claims-based-identity

I need to search user in identity server by using custom claim i.e. 'cnic' as a filter. I'm sending the following request packet in postman for this purpose but it gives me error. I'm using version 5.11.0 of identity server. Description of custom claim mapping is attached below.
[custom claim mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnSHL.png)

[postman request-response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unezw.png)

Comment: What is the version of IS that you use? Have you created a scim claim and mapped the cnic custom claims? If so add those details as well. If you haven't created a scim claim follow https://medium.com/p/71621f62c5d3

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you have created a local claim as cinc, in order to manage that claim value through SCIM APIs, you should have a mapping between a SCIM claim and the local claim.

1. Open the `scim2-schema-extension.config` file located in the `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/` and add the scim attribute definition before the last element of the JSON array (i.e. urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User should be the last JSON object)
   It would be as follow. You can change the metadata appropriately.

```
{
"attributeURI":"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User:cnic",
"attributeName":"cnic",
"dataType":"string",
"multiValued":"false",
"description":"National Identity Number.",
"required":"false",
"caseExact":"false",
"mutability":"readWrite",
"returned":"default",
"uniqueness":"none",
"subAttributes":"null",
"canonicalValues":[],
"referenceTypes":[]
}
```

2. Add the attributeName of the above-added attribute into `scim2-schema-extension.config file`, as a **subAttribute of the urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User attribute** (which is the last one in the file)
   Then it would look likes follows.

```
"subAttributes":"verifyEmail askPassword employeeNumber costCenter organization division department manager pendingEmails accountLocked accountState emailOTPDisabled emailVerified failedEmailOTPAttempts failedLoginAttempts failedLoginAttemptsBeforeSuccess failedLoginLockoutCount failedPasswordRecoveryAttempts failedSMSOTPAttempts failedTOTPAttempts isLiteUser lastLoginTime lastLogonTime lastPasswordUpdateTime lockedReason phoneVerified preferredChannel smsOTPDisabled tenantAdminAskPassword unlockTime accountDisabled dateOfBirth isReadOnlyUser pendingMobileNumber forcePasswordReset oneTimePassword verifyMobile country cnic",
```

3. Restart the IS and login into the management console.
   Navigate to Main menu-> Identity tab -> Claims .
   Click `Add` under `Claims`.
   Click `Add External Claim` and enter the following values. Then click on `Add`.

```
Dialect URI: urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User
External Claim URI: urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User:cnic (Attribute URI defined in the previous step)
Mapped Local Claim: http://wso2.org/claims/cnic
```

[image]

4. Then you can invoke the SCIM search as follows.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users/.search' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:SearchRequest"
    ],
    "attributes": [
        "userName"
    ],
    "filter": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User:cnic eq 123456",
    "domain": "PRIMARY",
    "startIndex": "1",
    "count": "10"
}'
```

[image]

Ref: Those steps are described well [here](https://medium.com/p/71621f62c5d3)